# Boolean Simplification questions

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm having some trouble getting a handle with this course. We are starting Boolean algebra and my professor wants us simplify the following:

Im sorry for the ignorance but I can't find a good reference to solve the problem.

1. $[XY'(Z+YW)+X'Y']Z$
2. $XY'+ X(Y+Z)'+ Y(Y+Z)'$

I am assuming the "()" with "'" means the over-score above the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use [these](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/logicgates-130704010044-phpapp01/95/computer-organization-logic-gates-boolean-algebra-combinational-circuits-12-638.jpg?cb=1372899841) rules to solve the questions.

1. **[XY'(Z+YW)+X'Y']Z => [XY'Z + XY'YW + X'Y']Z** *(Distributive Law)*=> [XY'Z+X'Y']Z *(Complementary Law)* **=> XY'Z+X'Y'Z => Y'Z(X+X')** *(Distributive Law)* **=> Y'Z** *(Complementary Law followed by Law of Intersection)*
2. **XY'+ X(Y+Z)'+ Y(Y+Z)'=> XY' + XY'Z' + Y(Y'Z')** *(De Morgan's Law and Distributive Law)*=> XY'(1+Z)  *(Distributive Law and Complementary Law)*  => XY' *(Law of Union followed by Law of Intersection)*

Comment: Hi Ashish Gupta,

Comment: @joash Hi. Did you understand what I did?

Comment: Hi Ashish Gupta,                                                                                                               Just have some question on your answers....  on the 1st question could you elaborate how XY'YW  been gone in the expression and result on [XY'Z+X'Y']Z..... and on the second question why does X(Y+Z)' became xy+xz isn't suppose to be xy'z'

Comment: Corrected the mistake in the second question. As for the first question, XY'YW can be written as X(Y'Y)W. Y'Y = 0 as per the Complementary law, and anything multiplied by 0 is 0 as per the Law of Intersection. As for [XY'Z+X'Y']Z, I just opened the bracket. XY'ZZ is same as XY'Z because ZZ = Z as per Idempotent Law.

Comment: thnks men for the big help...

Comment: hi Ashish Gupta, 1 more question can you check out this equation..                          X’YZ + XY’Z’ + X’Y’Z’ + XY’Z + XYZ
 my answer is x'yz+y'z'+xz but badly not sure of it!

Comment: hi  Ashis Gupta , can you check this equation X’YZ + XY’Z’ + X’Y’Z’ + XY’Z + XYZ my answer is x'yz+y'z'+xz but badly not sure of it! can you check thnks in advance